# if command in bash using regex on a MacOS computer

Tags: regex, macos, bash

I'm having trouble with an if command that utilizes a regex in a bash script on MacOS.  I've heard MacOS can be tricky in this way, and I think I'm discovering that.

I've tried two different patterns that I've successfully tested at several online regex test sites.

Here's the testregex.sh script:

```
pattern="http:\/\/[^\/].+:\d{2,4}\/?"
goodstring="http://www.google.com:3000/"
badstring="http://www.google.com3000"

if echo $goodstring | sed -n $pattern
then echo "goodstring is good"
else echo "goodstring is bad"
fi

if echo $badstring | sed -n $pattern
then echo "badstring is good"
else echo "badstring is bad"
fi

if [[ [$goodstring] =~ [$pattern] ]];
then echo "goodstring is good"
else echo "goodstring is bad"
fi

if [[ [$badstring] =~ [$pattern] ]];
then echo "badstring is good"
else echo "badstring is bad"
fi

if echo $goodstring | grep --quiet $pattern
then echo "goodstring is good"
else echo "goodstring is bad"
fi

if echo $badstring | grep --quiet $pattern
then echo "badstring is good"
else echo "badstring is bad"
fi
```

And the result:

```
./testregex.sh 
sed: 1: "http:\/\/[^\/].+:\d{2,4 ...": extra characters at the end of h command
goodstring is bad
sed: 1: "http:\/\/[^\/].+:\d{2,4 ...": extra characters at the end of h command
badstring is bad
goodstring is bad
badstring is bad
goodstring is bad
badstring is bad
```

Now, if I change the pattern to: `pattern="http:\/\/(?!\/).+:\d{2,4}\/?"` and rerun the script, I get:

```
./testregex.sh 
sed: 1: "http:\/\/(?!\/).+:\d{2, ...": extra characters at the end of h command
goodstring is bad
sed: 1: "http:\/\/(?!\/).+:\d{2, ...": extra characters at the end of h command
badstring is bad
goodstring is good
badstring is good
goodstring is bad
badstring is bad
```

As you can see, with the first pattern, goodstring and badstring are always bad.  With the second pattern, goodstring and badstring are always bad when piping, but always good when using the square brace substitution thing with =~

What am I doing wrong or what should I do instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex isn't right for bash, and you don't need `[` around them when using them.  First `/` isn't a special char for bash regex (nor necessarily for `sed`), so don't need to be escaped.  Then bash, for my version at least, doesn't understand `\d`, so that should be `[0-9]` instead.  If I set pattern to:

```
 pattern="http://[^/].+:[0-9]{2,4}/?"
```

then the bash regex check lines become

```
if [[ $goodstring =~ $pattern ]];
```

and

```
if [[ $badstring =~ $pattern ]];
```

I get the expected results for "good" and "bad"

Also, if you use `egrep` instead of `grep` so it has extended regex support it gets the expected results as well.

I'm not sure your pattern is quite right though, depending on what you're really trying for.  It would, for example, match `http://test/blah:2435`

Comment: That's perfect, thanks! The pattern doesn't need to be too robust for my application of it.  If I run into any problems, I'll harden the pattern (ie change .+ to something more specific)